# Tensorflow Estimators: RunConfig - save_checkpoints_steps

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

So, I'm not to unfamiliar with Estimators, been using it since the contrib days.

I've been having some issues with *save_checkpoints_steps* in the **RunConfig** of the estimator. If I set the *throttle_secs* in the **tf.estimator.EvalSpec** to some ridiculously high value, essentially never doing an evaluation, then I get checkpoints saved at regular intervals of *save_checkpoints_steps*.

If it's set to some low number, then as soon as it runs, the regular intervals are out the window.

Here is an example of checkpoints, where *save_checkpoints_steps = 5000* and *throttle_secs = 600*

```
model.ckpt-1
model.ckpt-5001
model.ckpt-6432
model.ckpt-6433
model.ckpt-11433
model.ckpt-12777
model.ckpt-12778
model.ckpt-17778
model.ckpt-19155
model.ckpt-19156
model.ckpt-24156
model.ckpt-25000
```

So the first one works (5001) but as soon as the evaluation triggers, then the interval isn't as one would expect. Is there a way to get the checkpoints to be

```
model.ckpt-1
model.ckpt-5000
model.ckpt-6432
model.ckpt-6433
model.ckpt-10000
model.ckpt-11433
model.ckpt-12777
model.ckpt-12778
model.ckpt-15000
model.ckpt-17778
model.ckpt-19155
model.ckpt-19156
model.ckpt-20000
model.ckpt-24156
model.ckpt-25000
```

The extra checkpoints from throttle_secs is quite okay, I just want the checkpoints at exact intervals to be there as well.